# Real time Streaming Data Pipeline using Kafka Connect and Flink

Tags: apache-flink, apache-kafka-connect

I am planning to put together following data pipeline for one of the requirement.
IBM MQ -> Kafka Connect -> Flink -> MongoDB
Flink real time streaming is to perform filtering , applying business rule and enriching incoming records.
IBM MQ part is a legacy component which can not be changed.
Possibly confluent or cloudera platform will be used to house the Kafka and Flink part of the flow.
I could use some thoughts/suggestions around above approach.

Comment: System design questions depend on many NFRs. So, for example, [this](https://developpaper.com/mq-hive-real-time-data-integration-based-on-flink/) has a unique view. System complexity cannot be addressed easily.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a closer look at whether you really need Kafka Connect. I believe that IBM MQ supports JMS, and there's a JMS compatible connector for Flink in Apache Bahir: http://bahir.apache.org/docs/flink/current/flink-streaming-activemq/.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Kafka Connect i was thinking so that we can scale for large number of record processing in parallel and capability for message replaying and leverage fault tolerance capability.

Comment: You should be able to get all that with a direct connection from MQ to Flink, assuming a parallel source connector that supports replaying events.